# MDX - Running total (MAT) with attribute hierarchy or any combination

Tags: ssas, mdx

I am trying to get MAT with individual attribute and a Year-Month
hierarchy. Year and Month on rows are fine (please see left of attached image[image: MAT]) but I am unable to find a solution when Year is on columns (please see right of attached image). I tried different combination of Year-Month hierarchy and attribute hierarchy and Descendants,
Filter, etc function but none of them worked.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

It might help someone so posting the solution I have found.

It's using the existing Year > Month > Date hiearchy with a 'Month Of Year' 
attribute hierarchy.

Key here is StrToMember which return member to be used for the Year > Month > Date (Hierarchy)

```
with
MEMBER YearName AS 
RIGHT([TIME].[Year].CurrentMember.Name,4)

MEMBER MonthName AS 
[TIME].[Month Of Year].CurrentMember.Name

MEMBER [Measures].[Sales Value-MAT] AS
    sum(  
        LastPeriods(
        12,
        StrToMember("[TIME].[Hierarchy].[" + MonthName  + " " + YearName +  "]")
       ), [Measures].[Sales Value])

select  
         {[TIME].[Year].[Year].members * [Measures].[Sales Value-MAT]} on columns,
NON EMPTY { [TIME].[Month Of Year].members  } ON rows 

from  [SalesCube]
```

[image]

Inspired from last post in [this](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/71f9ae4f-b533-43fd-a189-ada5a342324b/using-two-levels-from-the-same-hierarchy-on-different-axis-for-ytd?forum=sqlanalysisservices) thread.